# Why is my margin:auto; off-center?

Tags: html, css

Not sure why this is happening but when trying to center .front by doing margin:auto; its off center quite a bit. Here is a picture of it:

[image]

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Proza Libre', sans-serif;
    background-color:#f7f3de;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.para{
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    right:-100px;
}
.links{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    top:-50px;
    word-spacing:30px;
}
.logo{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:16%;
    top:-100px;
    right:100px;

}
.front{
    position:relative;
    top:70px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="beach.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proza+Libre" 
rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Lucas Essex</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="para">
   <h1>Beach Corp Inc.</h1>
   </div>
  <div class="links">
      <a href="asdasd.com">FAQ</a>
      <a href="asdasd.com">About</a>
      <a href="asdasd.com">Social</a>
      <a href="asdasd.com">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://samuibeautifulbeachvillas.com/assets/samui-beautiful-
    beach-villas.png" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="gang">
  <img src="http://www.beaches.com/assets/img/home/rst-btc.jpg" class="front">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not given the image a width. Block level elements are 100% wide by default so any margin applied with `auto` will be zero.

Comment: So how would I center the image with out it being off center like that?

Comment: Add a width for the image as I said. Another part of the problem you have is the other image is in the way. To show that issue, remove the other image and you'll see things line up just fine.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Johannes As I said, the other image is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

there's no remaining space to margin your div.front 
the block element takes the full width of it's parent till you specify a value for the image width, 
like this:
`img.front {
    width: 500px; /*for example*/
    height: 300px; /*for example also*/
}`
and you don't need to make it block element.
or try to change markup to :

`<img class="className" src="http://examole.com" width="500" height="300"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add on your image some width like `width:99%;` and then add `margin:0px auto;`

Comment: Its still off center when I try.

Comment: I am on the phone. Check if the parent is take all the space - width if no add width:100vw;

Comment: Add some background color to your divs to see what are you doing